# Full screen Overlay Navigation on mobile only

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wordpress

This is more looking for source material, as I cannot find a working example of what I am looking for.  I have a Wordpress menu display regularly as inline links. However, when I go to mobile size screens I want it to turn nto a hamburger menu which overlays fullscreen over the content when open.

I can only seem to find menus that do one or the other.

I'm currently bringing in the menu with typical wp code

html

```
<?php wp_nav_menu( array( 'container_class' => 'main-nav', 'theme_location' => 'primary' ) ); ?>
```

Looking to essentially create something like the demos on [tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles](http://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles) 
but full screen I want the links to show on top

Comment: there is not enough code to work with.  Write the code what the html is displaying. you can also add link of website similar to what you want.

Comment: That's the problem I have, I can't find it. Hence why I am more asking for resources than for code. Something like these https://tympanus.net/Development/FullscreenOverlayStyles/ but when the screen is full screen, it displays the links at the top as is

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So first you need a media query to hide and style the 'main-nav' on smaller screens, something like:

```
@media(max-width:767px){}
```

and a media query for larger screens like:

```
@media(min-width:768px){}
```

And maybe additional ones to suit your personal needs. Then in the small media query do you styling so something like:

```
.main-nav{
    display:none;
    postition:fixed;
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 2000;
}
```

Then you also need a burger button to trigger, this will be hidden on larger screens and displayed in the smaller screens.

This button can then trigger the .main-nav to appear on click, I'd use jQuery something like this:

```
$(".burger-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".main-nav").fadeIn("slow");
});
```

Then in your .main-nav you'll need a button to close the nav and I'd also do that with jQuery:

```
$(".close-button").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $(".main-nav").fadeOut("slow");
});
```

It's quite simple and quick to code something up like this just treat it like 2 separate menus and style each in it's respective media query.

Comment: So essentially I need to make 2 individual menus?

Comment: Well the same menu just styled differently on different screen sizes. Standard style on bigger screens with your burger toggle button hidden and then usually absolute or fixed position styling with block list items. If you like your example link you can look at the styling there with inspector tools to see how it's done then just add your JavaScript